How to define size of radial-gradient css as a percentage?
How can we define the size of radial-gradient in percentages instead of pixels?
radial-gradient(circle 300px at 5% 20%, red, blue 100%)

I want the gradient to adapt to the size of its container instead of being fixed in pixels, but this syntax doesn't work :
radial-gradient(circle 30% at 5% 20%, red, blue 100%)

Anyone have a solution ?

Use ellipse rather than circle. You can use percentages for those. If you make the width and height the same you get a circle.
background: radial-gradient(ellipse 30% 30% at 5% 20%, red, blue 100%);


so it's a miss in CSS itself for radial-gradient(circle for %age option? Good tips for elipse thx

@Matrix you don't need the ellipse, only the percentage are enough. One percentage won't work because the browser won't know which axis to consider for the reference that's why it's invalid
